# Surrounding element by span onfocus not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a divider that is editable:

```
<div id="textArea" contenteditable></div>
```

I want to surround the user's cursor with a span the first time the user focuses on the span:

```
var textArea = document.getElementById("textArea");
textArea.onfocus = function(event){
    var inner = textArea.innerHTML;
    if(inner == " " || inner == ""){
        var range = textArea.getRangeAt(0);
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.innerHTML = "&#8203;";
        range.insertNode(span);
        range.setStart(span, 0);
        range.setEnd(span, 1);
        textArea.removeAllRanges();
        textArea.addRange(range);
    }
}
```

But this is not working, nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: the error occurs after

```
var range = textArea.getRangeAt(0);
```

because alert("Test"); doesn't work after that anymore!

Answer (score 2):

if (inner = " ") should be if (inner === " ")

Comment: Thanks, that works